# Existe alguma forma de se obter um "result" JSON usando a package utl_http do Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, pl-sql, https, oracle12c

Existe alguma forma de se obter um "result" JSON
usando a **package utl_http** do Oracle ?

O **status code** da rotina abaixo retorna **200** mas retornaria também um "response"
com uma conformação JSON , um ID de inscrição.

```
{
"id": 11111
...
}
```

Não consigo ler este "response" por **utl_http.get_response**.

Existe alguém método/function para se obter este retorno (JSON) ?

Não tenho como reproduzir por questões de segurança e sigilo.

Exemplo básico do código (dentro do possível)

E uma API de cadastro CRUD.

RInclusao.xxxx é apenas o cursor/campo que opera a coisa.

A dúvida é : Como no Oracle (**utl_http**) obter o **JSON** de retorno ?

```
declare
  url varchar2(4000) := 'https://....';
  VS_TOKEN VARCHAR2(42) := '.......';  
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  
begin
  content varchar2(4000);
  content :=  '{                                                         '||
                  '"name": "'||RInclusao.NOME||'",                           '||                   
                  '"mail": "'||RInclusao.EMAIL||'",                          '||                   
                  '"dateBirth": "'||RInclusao.DATA_NASC||'",                 '||                 
                  '"additionalInformation": "'||RInclusao.DADO_ADICIONAL||'" '||
                  '}                                                         ';
                        
      req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST');
      utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
      utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));  
      utl_http.set_header(req, 'token', VS_TOKEN);  
      
      utl_http.write_text(req, content);  
      
      res := utl_http.get_response(req);  
      
      dbms_output.put_line('HTTP response status code: ' || res.status_code);
      dbms_output.put_line('HTTP response reason phrase: ' || res.reason_phrase);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tinha muito mistério
acrescentar

```
res := utl_http.get_response(req);  
 
FOR i IN 1..utl_http.get_header_count(res) LOOP
        if nome = '"id"'  Then
          VS_ID := valor;
          exit;
        end if;
      END LOOP;
```